# Accurately debugging a called Userform in VBA excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, interface

I was wondering whether there is a smarter/more accurate method of debugging userform initializations in VBA that are called from a specific module.

Because when I write an erroneously piece of code in the Userform_initialisatize, I the error I receive states an error, but not where it occurs, the highlighted piece of code is simply `call Userform_intitialize` and I'm left guessing which piece of code in `Sub Userform_intitialize`  contains the error.

So incrementally building a userform with test runs after every small addition of code work effectively to create a stable Userform initilisation code. Because I know what I changed since the last successful run, but it would save quite some time if I immediately know where the error occurs, especially in cases where trial runs consume a lot of time.

So are there ways to extract in which line the exact error occurs within a called `Sub Userform_intitialize` in vba Excel 2016?

Comment: You can place a breakpoint in the begining of `Userform_intitialize` and execute step-by-step with `F8`. However I am a bit puzzled why do you call explicitly  `Userform_intitialize`; this code is called automatically (like a constructor or initializer of the form) when the user-form loads. You should not call it explicitly (by rules of good practice).

Comment: Wow, thank you! I feel like a cyclist that can finally see drag; instead of having to intuitively improve the hidden code, I can just see what's happening! Such an eye-opener :)

I first have to perform computations based on sheet-input that shape (the number of textboxes e.g. in) the userform, so it's a dynamic userform. I had difficulties with the whole dynamic loading and initialisation, so I ended up with this construction. But I comprehend the point, I need to practice with the exact hierarchy/order of the  (creation of the) userform more. Thank you for sharing @A.S.H !

Comment: I see your point. In that case I would make a separate routine that "re-initializes / re-calculates" the form dynamically, and this routine may be called from any place as well as from `Userform_initialize`. The latter should first do any initial construction then call the separate routine. This kind of separation of responsibilities is very beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @A.S.H already mentioned the handler of `Initialize` event should remain `private`. Thats because the `Initialize` event itself is private so it is intended to be handled by the instances itself and not by anybody else.

> So are there ways to extract **in which line** the exact error occurs within a called Sub Userform_intitialize in vba Excel 2016?

Regarding your question, yes it *is* still possible to extract the line number where the error occurred. But the lines needs to be part of the source code. Then the function `VBA.Information.Erl` can be used to get the line number. Example:

> UserForm module

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MODULE_NAME As String = "MyUserForm."

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     On Error GoTo Error_In_UserForm_Initialize

1    Const procName As String = "UserForm_Initialize"

     ' Some code here
2    Dim d As Date
3    d = Now
4    MsgBox "Hi from my userform! 'Now' is '" & d & "'", vbInformation, "Info"

     ' Here error occures, max. value of Integer is 32.767
5    Dim i As Integer
6    i = 40000

7    Exit Sub

Error_In_UserForm_Initialize:
8    Dim errorDescription As String
9    With Err
10        errorDescription = "Error '" & .Number & "'" & _
                            " with description '" & .Description & "'" & _
                            " occured in procedure '" & MODULE_NAME & procName & "'" & _
                            IIf(Erl <> 0, " on line '" & CStr(Erl) & "'.", ".")
11    End With
12    MsgBox errorDescription, vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub
```

Some additional readings about `Erl` [here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/Tip_2_Use_line_numbers_in_your_source_code.htm) or [here](https://vpalmu.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/trick-put-line-numbers-in-your-vb6-code-with-this-undocumented-feature/).